# Web API requests being redirected to index.html

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, react-router

I'm using the [.NET 5.0 React project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). When the app is deployed to my dev environment, some requests to the API controllers are being redirected to index.html. This does not occur when it's running locally.

Most routes continue to work when deployed however, and I cannot see a difference in how the ApiControllers behind them are configured vs the routes that get redirected to index.html.

Here's a controller whose routes are being redirected to index.html:

```
namespace DonationMembership.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class RedirectController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot configuration;

        public RedirectController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = (IConfigurationRoot)configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult OlcUrl()
        {
            var olcUrl = configuration[Constants.Settings.OlcSite];
            return Ok(olcUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's one whose routes continue to work when deployed:

```
namespace DonationMembership.Api.Controllers
{
  [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DonationLevelController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DonationLevelController> _logger;
        private readonly IDonationLevelService donationLevelService;
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot configuration;

        public DonationLevelController(ILogger<DonationLevelController> logger, 
            IDonationLevelService donationLevelService, 
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.donationLevelService = donationLevelService;
            this.configuration = (IConfigurationRoot)configuration;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<ODataResult<DonationLevelContract>> Get()
        {
            return Ok(donationLevelService.GetDonationLevels());
        }
  }
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks! And yes I am using the '/api' prefix when making requests to my redirect route :)

**EDIT:**

My Startup.cs:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ConfigureDeps(services);

    ConfigureSwagger(services);

    ConfigureJwt(services);

    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = Constants.Settings.ClientPath;
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyApp v1"));
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCertificateForwarding();

    // UseAuthentication() must come before UseAuthorization() for JWT config to work
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

I haven't included the contents of my three Configure*() helpers. They aren't doing anything related to controller or route configurations.

Comment: The react app middleware handles unhandled request and redirects them to index.html. I’d check if the controller route is configured correct and maybe post Configure method in your startup.cs here would help identify the issue.

Comment: @weichch I updated to include my Startup.cs, thanks for reviewing.

Comment: I worked around this issue by splitting the client and API into separate projects. Without the SPA dlls in the deploy folder on the API, all requests went through without redirects. I'm leaving this question open since I didn't solve it, I would still really like to know how to keep the API and client together without redirect affecting my API calls.